# How to use POST request to create an object in C# API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, object

So I'm trying to make this parking ticket system and I'm currently creating these objects manually in the code for testing. Now I've come to the step where my POST request in postman should be able to create an object in the memory of the app. I've got two classes one for a ''Car'' and one for the ''Ticket''.

```
public class Car
    {

        public string regNr { get; set; }


        public string carBrand { get; set; }


        public string carColor { get; set; }

        public List<Ticket> ticketlist {get; set;}
        
        public Car()
        {
            this.ticketlist = new List<Ticket>();
            
        }
        public void addNewTicket(Ticket newTicket)
        {
            
            ticketlist.Add(newTicket);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Ticket
    {
       

      
        public int ticketID { get; set; } = 0;

        
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

       
        public string comment { get; set; }


       
        public int parkingAreaID { get; set; }

       
        public int parkingsOfficerID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

---

```
List<Bil> list = new List<Car>();
public void Post([FromBody]Bil val)
        {
 
            list.Add(val);
        }
```

The GET requests work and I want to be able to add a new ticket to a registration number by using my post request.
My current output is this;

```
{
    "regNr": "BT66358",
    "carBrand": "BMW",
    "carColor": "Yellow",
    "ticketlist": [
        {
            "ticketID": 1,
            "date": "2020-12-12T17:49:34.4000401+01:00",
            "comment": "very bad parking",
            "parkingsAreaID": 1,
            "parkingsOfficerID": 2
        },
        {
            "ticketID": 2,
            "date": "2020-12-12T17:49:34.4000401+01:00",
            "comment": "very bad parking",
            "parkingsAreaID": 2,
            "parkingsOfficerID": 2
        }
    ]
}
---------------UPDATE-----------

Bil = Car
botliste = ticketlist
liste = list
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3UaO.png
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to pass an object by using a POST request

Comment: what is Bil? What is its structure?

Comment: @AleksandrKurilov Oh my bad its a typ from my language, its the ''Car'' class

Comment: You just want to add "val" to the "list"?

Comment: @AleksandrKurilov Yes, the val needs to get added to ticketlist for that registration number

Comment: If "[FromBody] Bil val" is car, then we cannot add it to tickets because it is not a ticket.

Comment: So instead of ''[FromBody] Car val'' it should be Ticket val?

Comment: You need to take tickets from "val" and add them to the "list" if the list already contains this car, and if it does not, then you need to add "val" to the "list"?

Comment: var bil = liste.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.regNr, val.regNr)) this line is throwing an error saying val is null. And that object reference is not set to an instance

Comment: You need to add a val check before use it, for example: if(val == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Car data must be filled");
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val.regNr))
            {
                return BadRequest("Reg number must be filled");
            }

Comment: @AleksandrKurilov but why is it null? the data I'm using with POST is not empty

Comment: Have you specified Content-Type: application / json?

Comment: @AleksandrKurilov Yes, basically it says my val is empty and null when sending POST. Im using postman

Comment: Check out my answer, I updated it.

Comment: @AleksandrKurilov Hmm I dont understand why I'm getting System.NullReferenceException Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Im using the same code as you

Comment: Show the controller code in full so that I can understand what is missing.

Comment: @AleksandrKurilov Thank you for your time, I've updated check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225878/discussion-between-aleksandr-kurilov-and-suzdar-ibrahim).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then most likely you just need to add some attributes, and you get something like this:

```
List<Car> list = new List<Car>();

[HttpPost]
[HttpPost("SomeRoute")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Car val)
{

    if (val == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Car data must be filled");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(val.regNr))
    {
        return BadRequest("Reg number must be filled");
    }

    var car = list.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.regNr, val.regNr));

    if (car != null)
    {
        car.ticketlist.AddRange(val.ticketlist);
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(val);
    }

    /// And return IActionResult
    return Ok();
}
```

P.S. Give a description of the Bil type to get a more detailed answer.

upd:

You can also add attributes to the fields of your classes that will validate the values, for example:

...

```
public class Car
{
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "regNr field must be at least 6 characters")]
    public string regNr { get; set; }
```

...

The "MinLength" attribute indicates that the value for this property is required, and must be at least 6 characters.

More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=net-5.0

upd2:

This is how I get to invoke this method:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Currently getting this error ''cannot convert from "Webapplication.model.car'' to ''Webapplication.model.ticket'' with your code